# Unable to access property in C# in Main()

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
class Program
{
    public string SSN { get; set; }

    // Return a hash code based on a point of unique string data.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return SSN.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},SSN");
    }
}
```

When I type the above code in Visual Studio, it always shows an error. The SSN in Main Method is not accessible? Why so? Is property not accessible within same class? I tried using **this.SSN** but yet no result. Help! 
I am new to programming. Thank you!

Comment: because SSN is not static

Comment: Well yes, it's an *instance* property, and `Main` is a *static* method. Which instance of `Program` do you think you're accessing the SSN of?

Comment: Admittedly the code you've provided *would* compile, with a suitable `using` directive - I assume you meant to write `Console.WriteLine("{0}", SSN);`?

Comment: @JonSkeet it will not because the variable is not static

Comment: @Sherlock: Look very carefully at the body of the Main method. It doesn't refer to the SSN properyty.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes correct, I assumed that the proposed fix is on the main body

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems. One, `SSN` **must** be `static` if your going to use it in the `Main` method. Two, `Console.WriteLine("{0},SSN")` should be `Console.WriteLine("{0}", SSN)`.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string SSN { get; set; }

        // Return a hash code based on a point of unique string data.
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return SSN.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", SSN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it "must" be? If in main method you create an initialized instance of Program that also would work. Depends on what Abhishek is trying to do.

Comment: True, but if Abhishek doesn't want to create an instance, then it must be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the value of SSN from the Main method if you make it static. You also have the quotation marks misplaced for string formatting- the string is the first argument, and quotes should end before the comma and variable name.

Try this:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static string SSN { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       SSN = "212";
       Console.WriteLine("{0}", SSN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1. In `Console.Writeline` you specify the wrong syntax of string formatter.
   `Console.WriteLine("{0}",SSN);`
   The string to be pass into the format should be outside the string quotes and preceded by comma.
2. `public string SSN { get; set; }` You cannot access a non-static variable inside a static method.

   So specify the keyword static

   `public static string SSN { get; set; }`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication6
    {
       class Program
       {
            public string SSN { get; set; }

            // Return a hash code based on a point of unique string data.
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return SSN.GetHashCode();
            }

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",p.SSN);
            }
       }  
    }
```

The explanation behind the following code is that **you need to instantiate your *Program* class before accessing any property and/or methods since it's not declared as static.**

Answer (score -1):

Must be static

```
public static string SSN { get; set; }
```

or new instance from class

```
classname c1 = new classname();
c1.SSN;
```